# we are using efonvnc server in wince 5 device, its getting shutdown after 1 hour

Tags: windows

we are using efonvnc server in wince 5 device, problem is its getting shutdown after 1 hour.

Our project needs windows systems to connect with wince 5 devices.
we are using EfonVnc server in the wince 5 device and vncviewer in windows 7 system.

Everything works fine. OFten the connection gets closed after 1 hour window due to the EfonVNC shutdown in the wince 5 device.

Is there a way around for this?

Comment: Is there any error message or log saying why its logging off?

Answer (score 0):

If you right click the server icon in the taskbar, it gives you options to change the configuration. On the second page, there is a field to change the timeout value. I think that will solve your problem.

Comment: Depending upon your system config, you may have to change this value each time you start your system. I think efon vnc adds this timeout value to a registry, so you might want to set this value to a large number if you have access to your system reigstry settings.